# Samba (Cannot Write) issue

Tags: permissions, samba

I have setup Samba between two linux boxes (Ubuntu Desktop 12.10 and Ubuntu Server 12.04).  For some reason I cannot write to my samba share.  To me it looks like I have the correct permissions.  Below is my smb.conf, the filesystem permissions, and the steps I followed.  I definitely have it misconfigured but I cannot find out how.  Any help would be appreciated.  Craig

1. Created a user in ubuntu server (craig)
2. Created a user and password in samba "smbuseradd -a craig" set the password
3. Mounted the samba share from linux desktop.  This seemed to mount just fine
4. Attempted to write a file and it says that I don't have write permissions

Permissions on the server when viewed from the server "drwxrwxrwx 4 Craig Craig"
Permissions when viewed from ubuntu desktop "drwxr-xr-x  0 root  root"

```
[global]
follow symlinks = yes
wide links = yes
unix extensions = no

workgroup = Ubuntu Precise
security = user

unix password sync = yes

[homes]
comment = Home Directories
browseable = yes
writable=yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
guest ok = yes

[share]
comment = Precise File Server
path = /home/craig
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
writable = yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
```

EDIT:
      If I open my samba share as root then I can write to the folders.  I tried doing a chmod and chgrp but that didn't seem to have any impact.  I would prefer not to have to browse/write as root :)

Comment: I'd vote to move this to AskUbuntu.com

Comment: This is not a programming question. It is definitely off topic here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.  It wasn't in my samba settings.  The error was actually in how I was "permanently" mounting my samba share.

I was doing:

```
//192.168.1.11/craig /home/craig/musicServer cifs username=craig,password=MYPASSWORD 0 0
```

but I needed

```
//192.168.1.11/craig /home/craig/musicServer cifs username=craig,password=MYPASSWORD,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

Adding both file_mode and dir_mode solved it.

Answer (score 3):

The difference in owner printout is probably due to different UID/GID you have on your local and remote machines.

You can use `noperm` option at mount instead (no need for `file_mode` or `dir_mode`). This option turns off the local file permission check (so UID/GID inconsistency will be okay) and assume the remote identity you authenticated at mount. Remote access control is still enforced.