# No write permission for groups when using samba

Tags: debian, samba

I'm trying to set up a samba server for different users who do have different access to folders according to their system group assignment.

The problem is I cannot manage to get write acces for groups when mounting via cifs.

This listing shows how rights are set for the directory to be mounted

```
drwxrws---+ 31 root group1 4096 Okt 15 09:23 .
drwsrws---+ 19 root group1 4096 Okt 16 11:19 subdir1
drwsrws---+ 28 root group1 4096 Okt 16 11:52 subdir2
```

Here the rights of the target directory after mounting:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  group1    0 Okt 15 09:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  group1    0 Okt 16 11:19 subdir1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  group1    0 Okt 16 11:52 subdir2
```

This is my setting for the share in smb.conf:

```
[share_name]
path=/home/samba
read only=no
writeable=yes
public=no
force create mode=0777
force directory mode=2000
force group=group1
valid users=@group1
browseable=no
guest ok=no
inherit permissions=yes
```

This is the mount command used:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //server_name/share_name /mnt/share_name -o user=user1,gid=group1
```

user1 is member of group1

Here an extract of smbstatus :

```
Samba version 4.9.5-Debian

Locked files:
Pid          Uid        DenyMode   Access      R/W        Oplock           SharePath   Name   Time
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
19778        1005       DENY_NONE  0x80        RDONLY     NONE             /home/samba   .   Fri Oct 18 21:36:35 2019
```

I do not understand what should be done to get write permissions for groups. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Samba (Cannot Write) issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631510/samba-cannot-write-issue?rq=1) gives the answer at least for mounting on linux with cifs:

mount -t cifs //server_name/share_name  /mnt/share_name -o user=user1,gid=group1,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770